# Flutter FirebaseUser how to access the user data

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am learning Firebase with Flutter.
Currently making an anonymous login option, here is the class I created:

```
class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  
  
  // sign in anonymously

  Future signInAnonymous() async {
    try{
      // signs in as anon user
      AuthResult signInResult = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      // retruns currently signed in user, else null
      FirebaseUser userFromResult = signInResult.user;
      return userFromResult; // HERE: if I add .uid, the id object is displayed
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

In my login page after creating an instance and using the method, when I print the result I get `FirebaseUser(Instance of 'PlatformUser')` insted of the user information, here is the code:

```
onPressed: () async {
            dynamic result = await _auth.signInAnonymous();
            if(result == null){print('Error signing in.');}
            else{
              print('Signed in successfully');
              print(result);
            }
```

How can I access the user data?

UPDATE: If I change `return userFromResult;` to `return userFromResult.uid;` the id string is returned.
I still wonder, however, how to print the full object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that in version 0.13.x the user data is available, but in the version used in this example the bersion used is 0.16.x.

Answer (score 0):

Your Result inside of the onpressed is a dynamic type cast, but it is a FirebaseUser inside.

```dart
// onPressed Callback
            dynamic result = await _auth.signInAnonymous();
```

You can change your SignIn method with the right return type and use instead of dynamic the FirebaseUser.

```dart
Future<FirebaseUser> signInAnonymous() async {
  // [...]
  return userFromResult; // HERE: if I add .uid, the id object is displayed
}
```

```dart
onPressed: () async {
    FirebaseUser result = await _auth.signInAnonymous();
    print(result.uid); // should contain the id
    // [...]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I do not want to obtain the id, I would like to print the full object.

Comment: Then change the onPressed Function to: print(result.toString());
"result" is your full user object with displayName and so on. https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser-class.html

Comment: @MyrcaleDesign it did not work, all it displays is ```Instance of 'User'```